# How to get image and sound files from assets catalog in Swift?

Tags: swift, image, audio, mp3, assets

I'm trying to call files from the assets catalog in my swift project, but all the time I'm getting nil for images, and sounds.
When I'm using simple:

```
        let bgSprite = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "main_bg")
```

all work fine.
but when I try:

```
if (Bundle.main.path(forResource: "main_bg", ofType: ".png") != nil)
```

I get nil.
I've tried also:

```
if (Bundle.main.path(forResource: "main_bg", ofType: "png") != nil)
```

and

```
if (Bundle.main.path(forResource: "main_bg", ofType: "") != nil)
```

with same result.
I've also tried:

```
let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "main_bg", withExtension: "png")
```

and still nil.

When I import the files as a resources simple folder all works fine, but I wanted to start using the assets catalog.

I can't use the:

```
let bgSprite = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "main_bg")
```

because it does't work for sound files, and also need the ability to count amount of files in a function like this one:

```
func countGroupOfFiles(prefix: String, sufix: String, firstNumber: Int) -> Int {....
```

for files 
lights_0.mp3,
lights_1.mp3....
Any idea how to do it?
Can you help me with what I'm doing wrong?
Or maybe just not to use the asset catalog? (I'm not sure what is the difference)
Thanks :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create SKSpriteNode with an Asset Programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41819373/create-skspritenode-with-an-asset-programmatically)

Comment: Maybe because `Bundle.main.path` *is not* pointing to the asset folder?